# Is there information about statistics of the quality of treatment of slaves in pre-abolition USA?

Tags: united-states, slavery

In the USA before the abolition of slavery, it's easy to conceptualize that different slave-owners treated their slaves differently. There might have been sadists who tortured their slaves, and there might have been those who were kind with them and considered them almost family. And probably many between the two extremes who only cared about profit.

However, is there any information about their statistical distribution? Around how much percent were excessively brutal with their slaves, and around how much percent were treating their slaves humanely?

Please, no general opinions or politically motivated rants. I'm only interested in serious sources. The perfect answer would cite surveys or statistics, or if such information is non-existent, then contemporary sources from which an approximation could be reliably inferred.

Comment: I'll be suprised if there are any statistics that would provide that sort of information across the USA. I'd even be surprised if there were any sources from which you could reliably infer such statistics.

Comment: I think your question is more related with social science than history. BTW, could there be any statistics for the quality of treatment of domestic maids (legal or illegal) in the US now or for the past few decades? I strongly doubt it.

Comment: Absolutely there is a wealth of data. I would read the book Time on the Cross for a beginner's guide on how the Plantation System in the US South in fact functioned.  You'd be surprised at how good the paperwork was. "Hamilton's ghost" spread far and wide...